# Why do images move position while scaling in chrome but not in firefox or safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I have images placed with one on the left and two on the right.  When I resize the browser window the images scale.

The problem I am having is that in Safari and Firefox the images scale and maintain position correctly, but in Chrome the image positions change when I resize the browser.

**Here is a jsfiddle example to show the issue:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sSZFA/6/

and also a copy of the code:

```
        #col1{
           width:50%;
           float:left; 
        }

        #col2{
           width:50%;
           float:left; 
        }

        #img1{
           width:50%;
           float:right;
           clear:both;
        }

        #img2{
           width:50%;
           float:right;
           clear:both;
        }

        #img3{
           width:50%;
        }
    ​

            <div id="col1">
        <img id="img1" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img2" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <img id="img1" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img2" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg"/>
</div>
```

​
​

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of image 3 **from 50% to 49%** ....

```
#img3 {
width:49%;
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sSZFA/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the image width to 49% gives some ugly gaps but I did finally work out a solution.

It would seem that it is the "clear:both" css that is sending chrome crazy so I reordered the elements and removing the need for the clear attribute and it now works.

If anyone can provide a reason why my original code doesn't work in chrome, I would love to know.

http://jsfiddle.net/AC5BJ/1/

```
#col1{
   width:50%;
    float:left; 
}

#col2{
   width:50%;
    float:left; 
}

#img1{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    /*clear:both;*/
}

#img2{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    /*clear:both;*/
}

#img3{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

    <div id="col1">
        <img id="img3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg"/>
        <img id="img1" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img2" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">  
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <img id="img3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg"/>
        <img id="img1" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
        <img id="img2" src="http://fueledbyramen.com/fun/site/mpufun.jpg">
</div>
```